# First order logic without equality : "distinct" individuals considered equal

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) section of the wikipedia page about first order logic explains that, if $=$ is to be considered a non-logical symbol, then a theory using the language of 1st order logic can define it's own equality relation which should satisfy Leibniz's law and reflexivity.
What I don't understand is that the article also says that, in such case,

> an interpretation may now interpret two distinct individuals as "equal"

I don't understand what the article mean by "distinct".
Dinstinct in regards to what ?
At first, I thought it meant that two objects which would not be equal if $=$ was a logical symbol can be considered equal under the definition of equality given by the theory.
But since a theory that defines it's own equality relation must follow the same eqality axioms (Leibniz's law and reflexivity) as one which considers $=$ as a logical symbol, how can that ever happen ?

Because of this, I struggle to understand what's really different between a theory that considers $=$ to be a logical symbol, and one that doesn't and defines $=$ for itself.
I also fail to understand the point, for a theory that desires to have an equality relation, of defining equality itself instead of leaving $=$ as a logical symbol.

Comment: Are defined differences and similarities between $\equiv$ and $=$ relevant to what you are asking?

Comment: @DerekLuna I'm not exactly sure what you mean by $\equiv$. Could you clarify ?

Comment: Modular arithmetic, how $\equiv$ means equality in this new arithmetic. For example, $4\ \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not super knowledgeable about modular arithmetic, does $\equiv$ satisfy Leibniz's law (it's obviously refexive). If it is the case, it would be an example of a relation which satisfies the so-called equality axioms and yet can consider two distinct elements as "equal" ; that would at least assure me that such relations do in fact exist.

Comment: I am not too well-versed in logic, but $\equiv$ satisfies symmetry and transitivity as well. What else are you looking for specifically?

Comment: In basic arithmetic $7$ and $4$ are distinct elements, but $7\equiv 4 \pmod 3$, and so are the same thing, equal by the definition of this new symbol.

Comment: Wikipedia entry means that the binary relation $A(x,y)$ satisfies the property of being reflexive and satisfies Leibniz's law, form which symmetry and transitivity follows. That means that it is an *equivalence* relation that can "works as" equality but it is not "real" identity.

Comment: @Mauro I guess what I'm trying to say is that, since the case where $=$ is a logical symbol only specifies that $=$ is reflexive and follows Leibniz's law, how is it any different from any other equivalence relation that do the same ? What distinguishes it from other such relations to make it the "true identity" ? Is there something special about it that I'm missing, or do we just "pick" one such relation to be true equality ?

Comment: IMO the issue is: consider a FO language **without** logical symbol $=$ and introduce a "mathematical symbol" $A(x,y)$ with the properties above. It "looks like" identity from the point of view of the (first-order) language of the theory. See Derek Goldrei, [Propositional and Predicate Calculus: A Model of Argument (Springer, 2005)](https://books.google.it/books?id=B7UGnBbb2JoC&pg=PA247), **Ch.5.4 The equality axioms and non-normal structures**